# OCaml initializing list in loop for

Tags: ocaml

I am a beginner with OCaml. I would like to skip the first element of my list.

Here is my list:

```
let l = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;2;1];;
```

I want to use this in my FOR:

```
let l = List.tl l;
```

here is my full code:

```
let l = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;2;1];;
let n = 1;;
let counter = ref 0;;
for i = 0 to (List.length l) do
if List.hd l = n then counter := !counter + 1;
print_int(!counter);
print_string("\n");
let l = List.tl l
done;;
```

But I have errors in the DONE and it says syntax error.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `let` always requires a matching `in`. The full expression looks like this:

```
let var = expr1 in expr2
```

Since you're missing the `in` part, you get a syntax error.

However, the deeper problem is that you're trying to modify the value of `l`. The way you have defined `l`, it's immutable. You can't change its value. If you want to be able to change its value you can define it as a reference, as you have done for `counter`.

(There is another form of `let` used at the top level of a module. This form doesn't have a matching `in`. But your code isn't defining a top-level name, so this is not relevant.)